# Multivariate Time Series Leading/Lagging Relations

Tags: r, time-series, cross-correlation

Say I have an array of data of 10 time series $x_{i,t}$ at 1000 points in time. I wish to test the hypothesis that the first eight series are in some way a positive leading series of the other two.

So in other words (I think), the CCF between series $x_{1,t}$ or $x_{2,t}$ or $(x_{1,t}, x_{2,t})$ and $x_{j,t-k_j}$ for some group of $k_j$'s and all $2<j\le 10$ is positive so that when first eight series rise then in general so too do either/both my $(x_{1,t}, x_{2,t})$ and vice versa.

1. What type of model am I looking for?
2. Do I need to check for specifically a positive and specifically a leading series or can I just put the ten series into an algorithm of some kind that will determine which leads which and if so whether it's positive or negative?
3. How do I check specifically whether **both** of my lagging series are determined by **all** of my leading series or to what extent these relationships hold?
4. What's the best way to implement this in R?

Comment: What about VAR model and the notion of Granger causality (but also impulse-response analysis)?

Comment: Yes I have since discovered the VAR model and now plan on implementing it - I think this is what I was trying to describe above. I will also look into Granger causality and impulse response analysis. Thanks.